# Java In and Out

Tags: java, loops, file-io

I am newbie to Java. I have this exercice from school to create a `BasicIO` class and `Main` class to read and write to a file .

However my code only reads the first sentence and prints it in an infinite loop.

BasicIO.java

```
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class BasicIO 
{

    BasicIO()
    {
        line = null;
    }

    public void readplzthx(String filename) throws IOException
    {
        FileReader f = null;
        BufferedReader rd = null;

        f = new FileReader(filename);
        rd = new BufferedReader(f);

        line = rd.readLine();   
        rd.close();
        f.close();
    }

    public void writeplzthx(String filename)
    {

    }
    //String fn;
    String line;
}
```

Main.java:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Main {

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws IOException 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        File f = new File("test.txt");
        BasicIO io = new BasicIO();
        //io.readplzthx(f.getAbsolutePath());
        //File f = new File(args[1]);
        io.readplzthx(f.getAbsolutePath());
        do
        {
        //  io.readplzthx(f.getAbsolutePath());
            System.out.println(io.line);
        } while (io.line != null);
    }   

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that you're having trouble is that you open the file, read in the first line, and close it.  You need to keep the file open between calls to readplzthx and clean up after yourself when you're done.

Comment: Ok thanks. I think i follow too much the tutorial so I make this exercice more diffcult. They said I have to print the output in the Main class. Actually print the content in the readplzthx() is what i should do in the first place

Answer (score 2):

```
    do
    {
    //  io.readplzthx(f.getAbsolutePath());
        System.out.println(io.line);
    } while (io.line != null);
```

That's your infinite loop. `io.line` doesn't change inside the loop.

Even when that's fixed, though, you'll still have the same problem. You only want to open the file once, then read from it repeatedly.

Comment: It looks like he commented out the offending code.  The real issue is that the readplzthnx method always returns the same line (the first one) from the file.

Answer (score 1):

Three hints:

- `readplzthx` shouldn't re-open the file every time it's called;
- call `readplzthx` inside the loop so that you read a new line on each iteration;
- make sure you correctly handle reaching the end of your input file.

Answer (score 1):

You re-load the file at each loop iteration. You should create the reader before the loop, then call `reader.readLine()` in the loop iteration so that your io.line value isn't always the first line.

Comment: His readplzthnx method opens the file, reads a line, then closes the file.  Because of this, everytime through the loop he gets the same first line over and over again.

Answer (score 0):

In your `readplzthx` method, you're opening the file, reading in a line and then closing the file. So that's the first problem. This is why you're only getting one line.

You're setting the class's package-private member `line` to the line you read from the file. Your `do-while` loop is based on the condition that `io.line` is not null. This will always hold true. This is why you're in an infinite loop.

So here are some hints for your `BasicIO` class:

- Write explicit methods to open and close the file/stream.
- Write a state-inspection method that tells you whether you are at the end of the file, or if there is more content to read. You can use this in your `while` loop.
- Write a method that returns a line from the currently-open file; you can use this inside your loop.

All you need to do now is put these three pieces together.

Good luck!